# Create two tables in database wordpress

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I am new to wordpress development. I am writing a plugin that when the plugin is activated, these two tables are created. But only the first one was created as my desire. I don't know why, please help me.

```php
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'create_tables_in_db' );
function create_tables_in_db() {

    global $wpdb;
    $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();
    $table_dm = $wpdb->prefix . 'dmtl_danhmuc';
    $table_dm_term_rel = $wpdb->prefix . 'dm_term_relations';
    $table_term_taxonomy = $wpdb->prefix . 'term_taxonomy';
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );

    // TAO DM-TABLE
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE $table_dm (
        id bigint(20) PRIMARY KEY,
        name CHAR(100) NOT NULL,
        active BOOLEAN DEFAULT TRUE NOT NULL,
        items_quantity tinyint(3)
    ) $charset_collate;";
    dbDelta( $sql );

    // TAO REL-TABLE
    $sql_rel = "CREATE TABLE $table_dm_term_rel (
        id bigint(20) PRIMARY KEY,
        term_taxonomy_id bigint(20),
        dm_id bigint(20),
        FOREIGN KEY (term_taxonomy_id) REFERENCES $table_term_taxonomy(term_taxonomy_id),
        FOREIGN KEY (dm_id) REFERENCES $table_dm(id)
    ) $charset_collate;";
    dbDelta( $sql_rel );
}
```

Comment: Activation hooks are notoriously hard to debug. For debugging purposes, turn on full error reporting and make a simple page that executes these commands to see if anything is obvious. Once you get it working you can move it back to an activation hook.

Comment: Enable [debugging](https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/) and get full error message and update in your question.

Comment: @ChrisHaas thank you for your suggestion. I turned on WP_DEBUG and figured out that I miss 'unsigned' on term_taxonomy_id of referencing table